# Work at Primefaces Extensions Custom Exporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have some dataTables on the web page and I'd like to export all to an excel file, like the web page images:

### [image: Web Page and File Excel Exported]

I'd like to export the footer like showed in page. I try to use rendered and exportable,both with boolean attribute, but no way.
    What might be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the customExport, doing the steps on the link [Steps to Custom Exporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf)
  When I debug the code, I see the mode to create the footers on the document exporter, which it's not consist the tag exportable (isExportable()). Into the method "tableColumnGroup(Sheet sheet, DataTable table, String facetType){", of the class ExcelCustomExporter, I need to add an if: "if(column.isExportable()){" to create a cell and add value to this, and another if, the same way, to increment the variable using in the method for(i++); only the if is true I create the cell, add value and increment the variable i.

See below the code modified:

```
protected void tableColumnGroup(Sheet sheet, DataTable table, String facetType) {
    ColumnGroup cg = table.getColumnGroup(facetType);
    List<UIComponent> headerComponentList = null;
    if (cg != null) {
        headerComponentList = cg.getChildren();
    }
    if (headerComponentList != null) {
        for (UIComponent component : headerComponentList) { 
            if (component instanceof org.primefaces.component.row.Row) {
                org.primefaces.component.row.Row row = (org.primefaces.component.row.Row) component;
                int sheetRowIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
                Row xlRow = sheet.createRow(sheetRowIndex);
                int i = 0;
                for (UIComponent rowComponent : row.getChildren()) {
                    UIColumn column = (UIColumn) rowComponent;
                    String value = null;
                    if (facetType.equalsIgnoreCase("header")) {
                        value = column.getHeaderText();
                    } else {
                        value = column.getFooterText();

                    }
                    int rowSpan = column.getRowspan();
                    int colSpan = column.getColspan();

                    Cell cell = xlRow.getCell(i);

                    if (rowSpan > 1 || colSpan > 1) {
                        if (rowSpan > 1) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);
                            Boolean rowSpanFlag = false;
                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    rowSpanFlag = true;
                                }

                            }
                            if (!rowSpanFlag) {
                                cell.setCellValue(value);
                                cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                                        sheetRowIndex, //first row (0-based)
                                        sheetRowIndex + (rowSpan - 1), //last row  (0-based)
                                        i, //first column (0-based)
                                        i  //last column  (0-based)
                                ));
                            }
                        }
                        if (colSpan > 1) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);

                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    cell = xlRow.createCell((short) ++i);
                                }
                            }
                            cell.setCellValue(value);
                            cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
                                    sheetRowIndex, //first row (0-based)
                                    sheetRowIndex, //last row  (0-based)
                                    i, //first column (0-based)
                                    i + (colSpan - 1)  //last column  (0-based)
                            ));
                            i = i + colSpan - 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //TODO TRATAR E VERIRIFICAR SE  O VALUE PODE SER EXIBIDO
                        if (column.isExportable()) {
                            cell = xlRow.createCell((short) i);
                            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); j++) {
                                CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(j);
                                if (merged.isInRange(sheetRowIndex, i)) {
                                    cell = xlRow.createCell((short) ++i);
                                }
                            }
                            cell.setCellValue(value);
                            cell.setCellStyle(facetStyle);
                        }    
                    }
                    if (column.isExportable()) {
                        i++;
                    }   
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Screnshoot, but the JAN to MAY:

[image: Exporter Customized - Footer ok]